# Wrong alignment of subviews in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I have the following code, which creates `UIView`, and some of its subViews, and adds them to a `UIScrollView`, all in a loop :

```
    var count:CGFloat=bookScrollView.frame.minX

    for var i=0;i<10;i++ {  
        var view=UIView(frame: CGRect(x: count + 20, y: bookScrollView.frame.minY + 30, width: 200, height: 300))
        view.backgroundColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true;

        var imageView=UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: count, y: view.frame.minY - 30, width: 150, height: 220))
       // imageView.image=UIImage(named: "Sample_Book")! 
        view.addSubview(imageView)

        var titleLabel=UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: count + 10, y: imageView.frame.maxY + 30, width: 185, height: 60))
        titleLabel.text="Head First Javascript" 
        titleLabel.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()
        titleLabel.font=UIFont(name: "Menlo-Bold ", size: 15)
        titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        titleLabel.textColor=UIColor.grayColor()
        view.addSubview(titleLabel)

        bookScrollView.addSubview(view)
        count+=220
    }

    bookScrollView.contentSize=CGSize(width: count, height: 200)
```

It works fine,except the fact that other than in the first `view`,`imageView` and `titleLabel` are not visible.

The label and the imageView have moved towards the right from the second view onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Frames are expressed according to the superview's coordinate space.*

Since you're adding your image view and label to the `view` not the scroll view, their frames should be specified in `view`'s coordinate space. So you do not need to add `count` to their x position.

```
    var imageView=UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 150, height: 220))
```

And:

```
    var titleLabel=UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10.0, y: imageView.frame.maxY + 30, width: 185, height: 60))
```

**Note:** You should look into `UICollectionView` and autolayout for a more robust way of achieving this.